# What does the offset do in this line of MIPS code: lw $s0,4($t0)?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture

Not sure if the offset means fetch and store the instruction one line (4bytes) away from the 'load word's' program counter into register $s0,4($t0). How does this work in memory? Please provide examples if possible.

Comment: Again, this is explained in _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_ (look up `lw`).

Answer (score 7):

The functionality of LW and SW can be read in the MIPS Instruction Set, which Michael said already.

But, to make it quick, I still provide an answer here.
LW stands for Load Word. It loads a 32-bit word value to a target register (rt) from an address where this value is stored at.

```
LW rt, offset(base)
```

Let's make an easy example:

```
LUI T0, 0x8033
LW T1, 0x2550(T0)
```

The above code would now load the 32-bit word value located at address:

```
0x80332550
```

The value in LUI is the upper half of the address, while the provided offset 0x2550 is lower half. Now MIPS simply loads the 32-bit value from 0x80332550.

Let's say 0x80332550 contains following value:

```
0x80332550: 25 66 99 88 77 14 22 66
```

After the LW instruction, T1 would now contain the value 0x25669988. (If on big-endian, on little-endian it would be 0x88996625)

SW does nearly the same like LW, just that it stores a 32-bit value to the provided address instead of loading it. The rt register acts in that case as the value-holder.

Comment: Some nitpicking: `$t0` is the base, 0x2555 is the _offset_. And 0x80332555 would not be a valid address to load a word from since it isn't word-aligned.

Comment: @Michael Woops. Fixed that.

Comment: *MIPS recognizes that 0x8033 and 0x2550 are linked* is a strange choice of wording.  It's more like, MIPS does what it's told, and this is one way of getting the behaviour we want.  MIPS doesn't have to recognize anything, just do the math.

Comment: @PeterCordes Fixed that one too.